# Passing dynamic argument to app(indentifier) function in azure-monitor-workbooks

Tags: azure-application-insights, kql, kusto-explorer, azure-monitor-workbooks

I use Application Insight Workbooks.
I add query to workbook to select some data with [app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/app-expression) function.

I have drop-down with JSON Input

```
[
    { 
        "label": "Test",
        "value": {
            "m":"<subscription-test-m>/<resource group-m>/<instance-m>",
            "e":"<subscription-test-e>/<resource group-e>/<instance-e>"
        }
    },    
    { 
        "label": "Prod",
        "value": {
            "m":"<subscription-prod-m>/<resource group-m>/<instance-m>",
            "e":"<subscription-prod-e>/<resource group-e>/<instance-e>"
        },
        "selected":true
    }
]
```

I am trying to supply dynamically environment identifier to app function like:

`app("{Envionment:value.m}").requests;`

I get then `The request had some invalid properties: "Identity '[object Object]' could not be resolved"`

Does anybody know how to extract and provide json child value as literal to this [app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/app-expression) function?

Comment: Maybe there is workaround with setting another 2 variables based on {Environment:label}? What I try to achieve to correlate 2 application insights instances. So far I proved when the value is a simple string having one value, then I am able to get data with `app("{Envionment:value}").requests;`

Answer (score 0):

if you're stuffing an "object" into the value field, you *should* be able to use  `JSONPath` syntax for the parameter to get out part of a value:

[image: working workbook example]

however:

1. you need to use the query option with the JSON data source, it is more powerful than the "Get data from: JSON" option that expects the values to be strings, not objects.  The JSON data source also allows replacement of parameters inside the json content as well, like other query data sources do.
2. you'll need to re-order the fields in the json so the value is first, label is second.  the data source creates columns in the order it sees them in the objects, and the dropdown expects the first column to be values, second column to be labels.
3. you then use the jsonpath syntax when formatting the parameter `{parameterName:$.fieldName}`  parameters generally allow special kind of formatting if you use `:` and specific content after that still inside the braces.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/visualize/workbooks-parameters#format-parameters-by-using-jsonpath for jsonpath specifically

full working example:

````json
{
  "version": "Notebook/1.0",
  "items": [
    {
      "type": 9,
      "content": {
        "version": "KqlParameterItem/1.0",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "id": "d48de334-4741-4deb-b0fd-4f0f2df2acf6",
            "version": "KqlParameterItem/1.0",
            "name": "paramWithObject",
            "type": 2,
            "query": "{\"version\":\"1.0.0\",\"content\":\"[\\r\\n    { \\r\\n        \\\"value\\\": {\\r\\n            \\\"m\\\":\\\"<subscription-test-m>/<resource group-m>/<instance-m>\\\",\\r\\n            \\\"e\\\":\\\"<subscription-test-e>/<resource group-e>/<instance-e>\\\"\\r\\n        },\\r\\n        \\\"label\\\": \\\"Test\\\"\\r\\n    },    \\r\\n    { \\r\\n        \\\"value\\\": {\\r\\n            \\\"m\\\":\\\"<subscription-prod-m>/<resource group-m>/<instance-m>\\\",\\r\\n            \\\"e\\\":\\\"<subscription-prod-e>/<resource group-e>/<instance-e>\\\"\\r\\n        },\\r\\n        \\\"label\\\": \\\"Prod\\\",\\r\\n        \\\"selected\\\":true\\r\\n    }\\r\\n]\",\"transformers\":null}",
            "typeSettings": {
              "additionalResourceOptions": [],
              "showDefault": false
            },
            "timeContext": {
              "durationMs": 86400000
            },
            "queryType": 8
          }
        ],
        "style": "above",
        "queryType": 8
      },
      "name": "parameters - 0"
    },
    {
      "type": 1,
      "content": {
        "json": "value of `paramWithObject`:\r\n```\r\n{paramWithObject}\r\n```\r\n\r\nvalue of `e`: `{paramWithObject:$.e}`\r\n\r\n\r\nvalue of `m`: `{paramWithObject:$.m}`\r\n\r\n"
      },
      "name": "text - 1"
    }
  ],
  "$schema": "https://github.com/Microsoft/Application-Insights-Workbooks/blob/master/schema/workbook.json"
}
````